# Using nested JSON data in D3

Tags: json, d3.js

My react app makes an API call to grab some stock price data in JSON format.

[![enter image description here][1]

I don't know how to access each nested date's values and use them to make a chart. What would be the best way to go about this?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you want to chart this data. I'll assume for now that you are only interested in close prices.

You can use a javascript feature "map" to get the data into an easier shape for D3 to handle

```
// Assuming data is in a variable called data
// map over the keys (dates)
const cleaned = Object.keys(data.history).map(date => {
    return {
        date,
        close: data.history[date].close
    }
})
```

Your resulting data will be an array like this:

```
[  {
  "date": "2020-01-16",
  "close": "23.45"
  },
  {
  "date": "2020-01-17",
  "close": "25.15"
  },
  {
  "date": "2020-01-18",
  "close": "23.99"
  },
]
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment! Actually I want to create a candlestick chart using all of the values, but I was just unsure how to get started with this data structure. How do I iterate through these dates? I'm new to d3. I used fetch successfully but I see there is a `d3.json` option.

Comment: You can use `d3.json()`, d3 has a few "convenience" methods like this to make it "easier", but it's pretty much equivalent to using fetch

Comment: Hey! I edited my question. If you have a minute would really appreciate some advice on how to structure and parse the data in this fetch request. I used your method and it works but I am not sure how to implement it in the request `.then`

Comment: Did you morph this question into something different, or did you just add a bunch of stuff to it?

Comment: I just added an edit. The js file I added parses TSV data. I was wondering if I could instead fetch the JSON data and use the mapping code you provided then pass it using `d3.json` instead of `tsvParse. Thanks for replying btw

Comment: Part of the way that Stack Overflow works is to provide a reference of problems and their solutions, so if someone else has the same problem, then they can read it and find it useful. Changing the question makes it difficult to follow what has happened, my answer, for example, even though it is marked as correct, no longer answers the question, which is going to confuse a reader. Please revert the question to what it was, and by all means create a new question and tag me in it so I can help you with the next part

Comment: You are totally right. I changed it back and will tag you. Thanks! Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900405/parse-json-data-in-d3